# What happen if multiple threads will call await() method of CountDownLatch?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, countdownlatch

What happen if multiple threads will call await() method of CountDownLatch?

We have for example 3 threads Thread1, Thread2, Thread3. Thread1 has running job. Thread2,Thread3 will call await method. What will be a result?

Thread2 will be resumed at the same time as Thread3 or Thread3 will wait for Thread2 ending?

Comment: Re, "...at the same time..." Those words have very little meaning.  All you really can say about `countdownlatch.await()` is that it will decrement the value of the `countdownlatch`, and it will not return until the value is less than or equal to zero. There is no specification that says _how soon after_ the value reaches zero the call will return. On a system that has fewer processors than the number of `await()`ing threads, it would be physically impossible for all of the threads to wake up at the "same time."

Answer (score 2):

`Thread2` and `Thread3` will get waken up sequencely, but the time difference is really small. And there is no guarantee which of them will get waken up first. Basically, *Thread2 will be resumed at the same time as Thread3*.